# Error in util-packages of Ubuntu 16.04 while installing upgrades

Tags: upgrade, updates, scripts

I tried to install `numpy` package for python using the command -

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

I get the following error:

```
*Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  python-dev python-nose python-numpy-dbg python-numpy-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 203 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,763 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,598 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'runlcactivator' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service lightdm at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service runlcactivator if started
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux*
```

Kindly suggest some solution

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error, in my case some LSB headers were missing from a certain `runlcactivator` script in `etc/init.d`.

I tried removing that script altogether from `etc/init.d` and the problem got resolved.